# An issue that might lay in the code which I don't see (using a ledstrip) Atmel Studio 6.1

Tags: c

I am using Atmel Studio 6.1 and this is the code that I use, beside this i also got another code called "ledstrip.h". Which basically is an 1 dimensional array.
This is something for my study.
I am trying to send 12 bytes through a 'ledstrip'

code:

```
#define SPI_SS_bm PIN4_bm
#define SPI_MOSI_bm PIN5_bm
#define SPI_MISO_bm PIN6_bm
#define SPI_SCK_bm PIN7_bm

#define MIN_VALUE  0.4
#define F_CPU   32000000UL
#define P 128
#define FOO 0

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "ledstrip.h"




void spi_init(void);
uint8_t spi_transfer(uint8_t data);
const uint8_t *ptr = image;
uint8_t num[12];

int line;
int g;
int data;
int i;

void row (const uint8_t *j)
{
uint32_t row2 = 0;
for(g = 0; g < 4; g++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        row2 = (row2 << 3) | pgm_read_byte(j);
        j++;
    }
    
    num[3*g] = (uint8_t) (row2 >> 16);  //put bytes in the right order
    num[3*g+1] = (uint8_t) (row2 >> 8);
    num[3*g+2] = (uint8_t) (row2);
}
}


void spi_initialisation(void)
{
PORTC.DIRSET = SPI_SCK_bm|SPI_MOSI_bm|SPI_SS_bm;
PORTC.DIRCLR = SPI_MISO_bm;
SPIC.CTRL = (!SPI_CLK2X_bm) |   // no double clock speed

SPI_ENABLE_bm |                 // SPI enable
!SPI_DORD_bm |                  // data order, MSB first
SPI_MASTER_bm |                 // master
SPI_MODE_0_gc |                 // mode 0
SPI_PRESCALER_DIV4_gc;          // Presc. 4 (@2 MHz,500kHz)
}

void spi_init(void)
{
PORTC.DIRSET = PIN7_bm|PIN5_bm|PIN4_bm;     // 7: MOSI 5: SCK
PORTC.OUTCLR = PIN4_bm;                     // 4: latch enable
PORTD.DIRSET |= PIN3_bm|PIN1_bm;            // 3: MOSI 1: SCK

USARTC1.BAUDCTRLA = 0;                      // baud rate FCPU/2
USARTC1.BAUDCTRLB = 0;                      //
USARTC1.CTRLC = USART_CMODE_MSPI_gc;        // SPI mode
USARTC1.CTRLA = 0;                  // no   interrupts
USARTC1.CTRLB = USART_TXEN_bm;              // enable transmit

USARTD0.BAUDCTRLA = 0;                      // baud rate FCPU/2
USARTD0.BAUDCTRLB = 0;                      //
USARTD0.CTRLC = USART_CMODE_MSPI_gc;        // SPI mode
USARTD0.CTRLA = 0;                  // no interrupts
USARTD0.CTRLB = USART_TXEN_bm;              // enable transmit
}

void init_timer_phi(void)
{
TCE0.CTRLA = TC_CLKSEL_DIV8_gc;     // prescaling P
TCE0.CTRLB = TC_WGMODE_NORMAL_gc;   // normal mode
TCE0.INTCTRLA = TC_OVFINTLVL_LO_gc;
TCE0.PER = 1440;                    // t = PER*FCPU/P =
                            //   FCPU*P/32M = 1 us
}

ISR (TCE0_OVF_vect)
{
ptr = ptr +32;

if(ptr >= image + 32 * 360)
{
    ptr = image;
}                   // send bytes to ledstrip
}

void init_inputcapture(void)
{
PORTC.PIN2CTRL = PORT_ISC_FALLING_gc;
PORTC.DIRCLR = PIN2_bm;                     // Pin 2 is input
EVSYS.CH0MUX = EVSYS_CHMUX_PORTC_PIN2_gc;   // Select PC2 as input
                            // to event channel 0
TCC0.CTRLD = TC_EVACT_CAPT_gc |             // Event capture
TC_EVSEL_CH0_gc;                    // for Channel 0
TCC0.CTRLB = TC0_CCAEN_bm;              // Enable Inp. Capt. Ch. A
TCC0.CTRLA = TC_CLKSEL_DIV256_gc;           // Start timer
TCC0.INTCTRLB = TC_CCAINTLVL_LO_gc;         // Set Interr. level Ch. A
TCC0.PER = 0xFFFF;
}

ISR(TCC0_CCA_vect)
{
uint16_t v;
v = TCC0.CCA;
if (v > MIN_VALUE) 
{                   // skip if measured value is too small
    line = 0;           // reset image
    TCE0.PER = (v * 360/(F_CPU / P));   // calculate periode
    TCC0.CTRLFSET = TC_CMD_RESTART_gc;  // restart input capture
}
}


void spi_write_byte(uint8_t data)
{
    PORTC.OUTCLR = SPI_SS_bm;
    spi_transfer(data);
    PORTC.OUTSET = SPI_SS_bm;
}
uint8_t spi_read_byte(void)
{
    uint8_t data;
    PORTC.OUTCLR = SPI_SS_bm;
    data = spi_transfer (FOO);
    PORTC.OUTSET = SPI_SS_bm;
    return data;
}


int main(void)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;
    spi_init();
    PORTC.DIRSET = PIN0_bm;
    PMIC.CTRL |= PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm;
    sei();
    
    PORTC.DIRSET = PIN4_bm | PIN5_bm | PIN6_bm | PIN7_bm;
    
while(1)
{
    SPIC.DATA = i; // send i
    while( ! (SPIC.STATUS & (SPI_IF_bm)) ); // wait until send

    PORTC.OUTSET = PIN0_bm; // store
    PORTC.OUTCLR = PIN0_bm;
    _delay_ms(100);
    i++;

}
}
```

Okay, so I got this code with no errors and warnings.
But when I run the program on my microcontroller ATXMega128A4U, I don't get the intended output.

There is a possibility that I didn't connect the pins of my 'ledstrip' in the right way with the pins of the microcontroller.
But if we consider that I did it like I intended to, the problem should be in the code.
The intended signal is 12 bytes long and with that I can turn RGB LED's on or off.
The RGB LED's are put together in a so called 'ledstrip'

Now what I'm getting is that some of the RGB LED's turn on and are Red Green or Blue.
What i should be getting is something like a chasing RGB LED row.
So you would see the LED's turn on or off at a certain frequency.

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the actual output? Could you please narrow down the code you show to only the relevant bits?

Comment: You're probably better off asking this on electronics.stackexchange.com as it's more likely to be about the avr register settings than the programming. Though you do seem to have defined several SPI functions which don't get called, which makes it more than a bit hard to determine the intent. Start off just sending something to the led strip which would cause some lights to come on every few milliseconds, and if you have a scope see if the data is present on the wire. Most the code you posted doesn't seem to get called, so post the smallest code which shows the problem.

Comment: I got a 32 RGB LEDstrip, so 32rgb leds means 32*3= 96 individual leds.
Each of this leds should be activated by a bit with a low or a high, a 1 or 0 so. So actualy I got 96bits that I want to turn on or off.
Finally I would get an image when I rotate the ledstrip very fast.